# How to fix these Unity errors?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I recently switched out some arrays for Lists in most of my scripts as they are easier to use. The problem though is that brought out some new errors. They are :

1. InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
2. ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

According to the errors, the problem is on line 96 of the Gorean Turret and line 37 of the POW_Camp. A couple other scrips also have that issue, but if I figure out what's wrong with these two I should be able to figure out how to fix the rest.

I searched up what to do about these errors and found a couple solutions. I changed the foreach loops to for (var i=0;) style loops. This was supposed to work, but unfortunately not.

My problem is how do I fix these errors. How do I need to change my scripts so there are no errors. As a side note, if you find something that can be shortened, please tell me. I have a feeling that the code is also longer than it needs to be.

Here is the POW_Camp Script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class POW_Camp : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject AmmunitionsDump;
    public GameObject Explosion;
    public GameObject Fences;
    public List<GameObject> Prisoners;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (AmmunitionsDump.GetComponent<Health>().CurrentHealth<=0)
        {
            AmmunitionsDump.SetActive(false);
            Explosion.SetActive(true);
        }
        //If the ammunitiondump is destroyed then destroy fences
        if (AmmunitionsDump.activeSelf == false)
        {
            Destroy(Fences);
            //Activate POWs
            for (var i=0;i<Prisoners.Count; i++)
            {
                if (Prisoners[i] == null)
                {
                    Prisoners.Remove(Prisoners[i]);
                }
                if (Prisoners[i] != null)
                {
                    Prisoners[i].GetComponent<PlayerData>().Captured = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the GoreanTurret Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GoreanTurret : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Projectile;
    public GameObject FiringPoint;
    public GameObject GunTower;

    public GameObject HealthBar;
    public List<GameObject> TargetsWithinRange = new List<GameObject>();
    public float FiringRange = 100;
    public GameObject CurrentTarget;
    public bool TargetLocked;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        InvokeRepeating("Shoot", 1, 0.5f);
        HealthBar.GetComponent<Slider>().maxValue = gameObject.GetComponent<Health>().MaxHealth;
        HealthBar.GetComponent<Slider>().value = gameObject.GetComponent<Health>().CurrentHealth;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        FindTargetsWithinRange(FiringRange, TargetsWithinRange);
        TargetManager(TargetsWithinRange, FiringRange);
        HealthBar.GetComponent<Slider>().value = gameObject.GetComponent<Health>().CurrentHealth;
        //Look at Target if Target is Locked
        if (TargetLocked)
        {
            GunTower.transform.LookAt(CurrentTarget.transform);
        }
        // If target is destroyed then set targetLocked to false and target to null;
        if (CurrentTarget != null)
        {
            if (CurrentTarget.GetComponent<Health>().CurrentHealth <= 0)
            {
                TargetLocked = false;
                CurrentTarget = null;
            }
        }
        // If one of the targets in the target list is destroyed then remove that
        foreach (GameObject possibleTarget in TargetsWithinRange)
        {
            if (possibleTarget == null || possibleTarget.GetComponent<Health>().CurrentHealth<=0 || possibleTarget.GetComponent<Health>()==null)
            {
                TargetsWithinRange.Remove(possibleTarget);
                
            }
        }
        if (CurrentTarget == null)
        {
            TargetLocked = false;
            CurrentTarget = null;

        }
        // If target is lost and there are still targets, then switch target
        if (TargetLocked == false && (CurrentTarget == null || CurrentTarget.GetComponent<Health>().CurrentHealth<0) && TargetsWithinRange.Count>0)
        {
            if (TargetsWithinRange[0] != null)
            {
                CurrentTarget = TargetsWithinRange[0];
                TargetLocked = true;
            }
        }
    }



    void FindTargetsWithinRange(float range, List<GameObject> TargetList)
    {
        Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(gameObject.transform.position, range);
        foreach (Collider collider in colliders)
        {
            if (collider.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerData>())
            {
                if (collider.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerData>().Captured == false && TargetList.Contains(collider.gameObject) == false)
                {
                    TargetList.Add(collider.gameObject);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    void TargetManager(List<GameObject> TargetList, float MaxRange)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < TargetList.Count; i++)
        {
            //If the Target is null or inactive then remove that target or if it has no health
            if (TargetList[i] == null || TargetList[i].activeSelf == false || TargetList[i].GetComponent<Health>().CurrentHealth <= 0)
            {
                TargetList.Remove(TargetList[i]);
                if (TargetList[i] == CurrentTarget)
                {
                    TargetLocked = false;
                }
            }
            //If the target is too far
            if (Vector3.Distance(gameObject.transform.position, TargetList[i].transform.position) > MaxRange)
            {
                TargetList.Remove(TargetList[i]);
                if (TargetList[i] == CurrentTarget)
                {
                    CurrentTarget = null;
                    TargetLocked = false;
                }
            }
        }

        //If there is no target and the TargetLocked is false then Set a new target
        if (CurrentTarget == null && TargetLocked == false && TargetList.Count > 0)
        {
            CurrentTarget = TargetList[0];
            TargetLocked = true;
        }

        // If target is destroyed then set targetLocked to false and target to null;
        if (CurrentTarget != null && CurrentTarget.activeSelf == true && CurrentTarget.GetComponent<Health>().CurrentHealth > 0)
        {
            if (CurrentTarget.GetComponent<Health>().CurrentHealth <= 0)
            {
                TargetLocked = false;
                CurrentTarget = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Shoot()
    {
        if (TargetLocked == true)
        {
            Instantiate(Projectile, FiringPoint.transform.position, FiringPoint.transform.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Maran, Both errors are self explanatory, first says you are iterating a collection which is changing inside `for/foreach` loop. Second error says you are trying to access an element which is out of index i.e `index > array.Length`. It would be great if you update your question with minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Neither of these errors would come about purely by switching the declaration of X from array to List

Comment: `for (var i=0;i<Prisoners.Count; i++)` I recommend you iterate this array backwards (i=Length-1, i--) if you're going to be removing items from it as you iterate

Comment: You cannot call `TargetsWithinRange.Remove(possibleTarget);` from within a loop that is `foreach... in TargetsWithinRange`; make it a for loop instead

Comment: For argument out of range errors make sure that you don't access an array item outside the length of the array. Particularly, if you're iterating an array and you reach the last item and decide to remove it, don't then try and access it again - your prisoners list could suffer this because you make a decision to remove at i and then immediately try and access at i again (needlessly I might add; put an if else in rather than an if null if not null). If you remove the last prisoner there will be no more prisoner at i causing an IOOB exception on the next access

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar Hi, I know what the errors are and what they mean, but my problem is I don't know how to fix it. The targets list will keep on changing. I'm not sure what I need to do to fix that. The reason I added the entire script was because I wasn't sure which loops needed to change. I use loops throughout the script. Do you have any idea  of how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both your classes you have loops where you are removing elements from your collections while you are iterating over them.

The first one causes the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` because after removing certain amount of elements you will iterate until reaching an index that is too high since your list/array is smaller now!

The other exception is pretty self-explanatory: You alter the collection while iterating over it with a `foreach`.

You can solve both cases using [Linq `Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) in order to filter out the `null` entries (requires `using System.Linq;` on top of your file)

```
// in general use the bool operator of UnityEngine.Object
// never do check for "== null" !
Prisoners = Prisoners.Where(p =>  p).ToList();
// This basically equals doing something like
//var p = new List<GameObject>();
//foreach(var prisoner in Prisoners)
//{
//    if(prisoner) p.Add(prisoner);
//}
//Prisoners = p;

foreach (var prisoner in Prisoners.Count)
{
    prisoner.GetComponent<PlayerData>().Captured = false;
}
```

Exactly the same thing can be done in your second script

```
// so first again we use the bool operator to check if the element target "existed
// then directly use TryGetComponent instead of GetComponent twice
// your order to check also made little sense ;) you should first Check 
// the existence of the component before accessing a value
TargetsWithinRange = TargetsWithinRange.Where(target => target && target.TryGetComponent<Health>(out var health) && health.CurrentHealth > 0).ToList();
```

---

Alternatively if it is important that the collection itself stays the same reference you could use [`RemoveAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall) instead like

```
Prisoners.RemoveAll(prisoner => ! prisoner);
```

and accordingly in your other script

```
TargetsWithinRange.RemoveAll(target => !target || !target.TryGetComponent<Health>(out var h) || h.CurrentHealth <= 0);
```

Comment: Hi, I tried using both of your methods, but it creates more problems than solutions. The POW_Camp script works fine, but the Turret Script does not. Your methods seem to interfere somehow with the Targeting System. It can no longer switch targets. The first target remains the current target even after it is destroyed. Is there some other way to fix these errors?